# Length of json array field in Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

Given: json string that represents array field selected as a result of query.

How to find out length of JSON array field in Big Query?

Comment: `... array field selected as a result of query ...` is quite wide open description! can you provide more details / example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See if this does what you want. It uses a JavaScript UDF to parse the JSON and then returns the array length.

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION JsonArrayLength(json_array STRING)
RETURNS INT64 LANGUAGE js AS """
var arr = JSON.parse(json_array);
return arr.length;
""";

SELECT JsonArrayLength('[1,3,5,7]');
```

Answer (score 8):

In case it may be useful for someone like me looking for the answer today:
I replaced the `JSON_LENGTH(json_string, json_path)` method from MySQL by `ARRAY_LENGTH(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(json_string, json_path)` in BigQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Below example is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT ARRAY_LENGTH(SPLIT('[1,3,5,7]'))
```

Comment: But it's not going to work if the array contains other JSON objects with arrays :) The question is so broad that maybe just SPLIT is sufficient, though; it's hard to tell.

Comment: agree. the answer usually as good as question is :o) but hope our answers still have some value for OP

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try! It finds opening/closing double quote counts for a string. It worked great for me.

```
SELECT 
    ARRAY_LENGTH(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(TO_JSON_STRING(my_json_column), r'"([^"]+)"')) AS key_count
FROM my_dataset.my_table
```